# Getting error while Updating Collection attribute name in the MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

So I have following structure of MongoDB collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("516c48631f6c263a24fbbe7a"), "oldname" : 1, "name" : "somename" }
```

and I want to rename OLD NAME to NEW NAME so it will look like,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("516c48631f6c263a24fbbe7a"), "newname" : 1, "name" : "somename" }
```

so I am writing this command,

```
db.element_type.update({}, {$rename: {'oldname': 'newname'}}, false, true);
```

But it is giving me this error

```
failing update: objects in a capped ns cannot grow
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem, per the error message, is that you're trying to update a capped collection, presumably with a `newname` that is longer than the `oldname`.

You can [read about capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) in the docs. They're designed to maintain their order, which is why you're running into this.

<s>If you must use a capped collection, perhaps you should remove and re-insert instead of updating.</s>

Comment: Like the link you provided says: you cannot delete from a capped collection.